# Rotate a Video in gstreamer

Tags: video, rotation, gstreamer, pipeline

I have this pipeline to record from two webcams simultaneously:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=300\
! "video/x-raw,width=800,height=600,framerate=30/1" ! videorate\
! "video/x-raw,framerate=30/1" ! jpegenc ! queue ! mux. \
pulsesrc device="alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" \
!  'audio/x-raw,rate=88200,channels=1,depth=24' !  audioconvert ! \
avenc_aac compliance=experimental ! queue ! mux. matroskamux name="mux"\
 ! filesink location=/home/sina/T1.avi  v4l2src device=/dev/video1 \
! 'image/jpeg,framerate=30/1,width=800,height=600' ! videorate !  \
 ! queue ! mux2.  pulsesrc \
device="alsa_input.usb-046d_0990_94D7DC5E-02-Q9000.analog-mono" \
!  'audio/x-raw,rate=88200,channels=1,depth=24' !  audioconvert \
!  avenc_aac compliance=experimental ! queue ! mux2. \
matroskamux name="mux2" ! filesink location=/home/sina/T2.mts
```

I'd like to rotate the video of the second Camera (/dev/video1) by 180 since it's mounted up side down, How can I do the rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `videoflip` element can do this for your. You probably want use `method=rotate-180` as option for this element. However this requires re-encoding of the image (e.g. jpeg-decode and jpeg-encode).

You may want to investigate the `GstVideoOrientation` interface. The `v4l2src` element implements this interface and allows control over some flipping options. You will need to write our own GStreamer application to get access to this interface though. Also since the flipping is then done in the hardware device itself it may or may not work for your device.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works but by using jpegdec - jpegenc the quality of recorded video is reduced significantly... actually the main goal of using JPEG was to capture in HD via the webcam, is there any other way to preserve the quality while flipping the video?

Comment: You have some control over the quality via the "quality" option of the "jpegenc" and perhaps "idct-method".