# How to add a GstVideoOrientationInterface to a Gst pipeline?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I'm trying to rotate/flip the video played by a plabin element (in C++). What I'm trying to to is similar to what asked in the question [Rotate a Video in gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659930/rotate-a-video-in-gstreamer) , but I prefer not to rely on the videoflip element. Instead I'd like to use the GstVideoOrientation interface (https://thiblahute.github.io/GStreamer-doc/gst-plugins-base-video-1.0/videoorientation.html?gi-language=c#interfaces) from the gst video library (https://thiblahute.github.io/GStreamer-doc/gst-plugins-base-video-1.0/index.html?gi-language=c).

The documentation of the interface itself and how to use it is pretty clear, but I can't understand how to add such interface to a GstElement.

There is some documentation in https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/interfaces.html and in https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/interfaces.html , but still I can't figure out how this works.

Below is the code sample I'm working with:

```
#include <gst/video/video.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

gint
main (gint argc, gchar * argv[])
{

    //...

    GstElement *pipeline;
    pipeline = NULL;

    gst_init (NULL,NULL);

    pipeline = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "playbin");

    g_object_set (pipeline, "uri", "an_uri", NULL);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appricieated

Many thanks

Comment: Well this is just an interface. An element may implement this interface or it my not. `videoflip` does implement `GstVideoDirection` for example. You cannot simply just tell a pipeline to flip - if you don't have an element what does the actual flipping what is supposed to happen?